# How to create and name two identical stateful components, where one uses Redux state and the other local state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

At the moment, I have a button named `AsyncButton` that is connected to the Redux store, reading a `isRequesting` Boolean value. Based on the value, the button will be disabled and show a `LoadingSpinner`:

```
function AsyncButton({ children, ...props }) {
  const isRequesting = useSelector(selectIsRequesting);

  return (
    <Button disabled={isRequesting} {...props}>
      {children}
      {isRequesting && <LoadingSpinner />}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

However, I now need an identical instance of this button, albeit where the `isRequesting` state is passed in via props. As such, I believe that I should disconnect the component from the store, make it presentational/dumb, so that any state it needs is drilled into it e.g.:

```
function AsyncButton({ children, isRequesting, ...props }) {
  return (
    <Button disabled={isRequesting} {...props}>
      {children}
      {isRequesting && <LoadingSpinner />}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Now, how do I name the container component that will pass `isRequesting` into the `AsyncButton` from the store? e.g.:

```
function ConnectedAsyncButton(props) {
  const isRequesting = useSelector(selectIsRequesting);
  return <AsyncButton {...{isRequesting, ...props}} />
}
```

Here, I have named it `ConnectedAsyncButton` but as I am new to Redux, I am not sure whether this is appropriate or not. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass isRequesting as props to AsyncButton component like code below.

```
function ConnectedAsyncButton(props) {
  const isRequesting = useSelector(selectIsRequesting);
  return <AsyncButton isRequesting={isRequesting} {...props}} />
}
```

You are accessing isRequesting prop correctly in AsyncButton component.

Comment: My question is about how to name the component. Please re-read thank you

Comment: Sorry to misinterpret your question. I dont think you can do that, but you can conditionally use props or redux state in same component.